# NextJS14 console.log that im not finding

Tags: next.js, cookies, console.log

Everytime that i refresh the page, this obj is logging in my terminal.

```
{
  set-cookie: 'authjs.session-token=eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2Q0JDLUhTNTEyIiwia2lkIjoiNXhRN0RZM3NHLU9CN0pybVRmQmtBWmJmNDZScXREdExuMnpneU54ZmlhLTN2ejBOc282bHd1NEtFSTJPSjJRVENJSnk2UDUtN1ZpTGlhMG0zQS0xOUEifQ..BX9lrp89YO4wXCdJHtl8Sg.Q5nQGARA1_771C2tB5iWI5eTQP0AIH__wVlVj9iqNLSj8G8OZfjiw809vztVHit5fRYDNG1EwAGx0NOHseoq7LrdGzukbqd6yu3T0FskADH3kLTZHyjQPd5Xf0I3SUo-9TT2U6dQGpDQkWQZ8Gm9Qa0J8Brym0zDDy-5dsCIDrPYBWMpzMV-gZ-U57x2XoLjg1ix4L24QTGrSYNI5_7BdVj3zz8Z-JbPP9No_H5uuS3R9PQLORBGcakfLYP2-yxOl9v83YEnDzBfXYRhzdcvOjSeFA7xt3VfuRRtHkIP4rgqVdPc5rQzuhbbDCn_G7JngkK_baL3GaS7PZ83yBpfjOJJ50xDW9kVbRuQV3F8PnVyKGL8VFhOnXDsaJFjakEj_4CvZoPFYdGQ-FQQ_cIWpgAJmUKB0v2gmUQmkPau-mjZklh8vtm70tLcQ3THbuNT.qD6GZurZfJsUmf_4FnmmaPxvgBzAR6ky4XlpfpGqWrg; Path=/; Expires=Tue, 19 Mar 2024 03:38:33 GMT; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax',
  x-middleware-next: '1'
}
{ x-middleware-next: '1' }
{
  set-cookie: 'authjs.session-token=eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2Q0JDLUhTNTEyIiwia2lkIjoiNXhRN0RZM3NHLU9CN0pybVRmQmtBWmJmNDZScXREdExuMnpneU54ZmlhLTN2ejBOc282bHd1NEtFSTJPSjJRVENJSnk2UDUtN1ZpTGlhMG0zQS0xOUEifQ..BX9lrp89YO4wXCdJHtl8Sg.Q5nQGARA1_771C2tB5iWI5eTQP0AIH__wVlVj9iqNLSj8G8OZfjiw809vztVHit5fRYDNG1EwAGx0NOHseoq7LrdGzukbqd6yu3T0FskADH3kLTZHyjQPd5Xf0I3SUo-9TT2U6dQGpDQkWQZ8Gm9Qa0J8Brym0zDDy-5dsCIDrPYBWMpzMV-gZ-U57x2XoLjg1ix4L24QTGrSYNI5_7BdVj3zz8Z-JbPP9No_H5uuS3R9PQLORBGcakfLYP2-yxOl9v83YEnDzBfXYRhzdcvOjSeFA7xt3VfuRRtHkIP4rgqVdPc5rQzuhbbDCn_G7JngkK_baL3GaS7PZ83yBpfjOJJ50xDW9kVbRuQV3F8PnVyKGL8VFhOnXDsaJFjakEj_4CvZoPFYdGQ-FQQ_cIWpgAJmUKB0v2gmUQmkPau-mjZklh8vtm70tLcQ3THbuNT.qD6GZurZfJsUmf_4FnmmaPxvgBzAR6ky4XlpfpGqWrg; Path=/; Expires=Tue, 19 Mar 2024 03:38:33 GMT; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax',
  x-middleware-next: '1'
}
```

I dont have any console.log in my app. i already deleted .next & node_modules and reinstalled both.

If anyone has some clue where is this console.log.

ps: it starts to occur when i log some data from session, but i removed all console and it doesnt disappears!

in .next/server/src/middleware.js when i search for some console.log i found this:

`\n// Uncomment to recalculate the estimated size\n// of an empty session cookie\n// import { serialize } from \"cookie\"\n// console.log(\n//   \"Cookie estimated to be \",\n//   serialize(`__Secure.authjs.session-token.0`, \"\", {\n//     expires: new Date(),\n//     httpOnly: true,\n//     maxAge: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER,\n//     path: \"/\",\n//     sameSite: \"strict\",\n//     secure: true,\n//     domain: \"example.com\",\n//   }).length,\n//   \" bytes\"\n// )\nconst ALLOWED_COOKIE_SIZE = 4096;\n// Based on commented out section above\nconst ESTIMATED_EMPTY_COOKIE_SIZE = 160;\nconst CHUNK_SIZE = ALLOWED_COOKIE_SIZE - ESTIMATED_EMPTY_COOKIE_SIZE;\n/**\n * Use secure cookies if the site uses HTTPS\n *`